# C#: como identificar título de planilha

Tags: c#, microsoft-excel

Bom dia pessoal, estou fazendo um conversor de excel pra txt e surgiu uma duvida, estava tentando fazer um algoritmo em que ele detecta o título da coluna e retorna erro caso a coluna tivesse o mesmo título, mas, como fazer par ele identificar apenas o titulo?

Nesse algoritmo ele apenas faz a comparação da coluna e linha e retorna o erro de coluna e linha igual.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dsPlan1.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++) //todo: dispara a contagem da quantidade de tabelas
            {
                try
                {
                    if (!TestaCampos(dsPlan1.Tables[0].Rows[0][i].ToString()))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (dsPlan1.Tables[0].Rows[0][i].ToString() != "" )
                            {
                                cmps.Add(dsPlan1.Tables[0].Rows[0][i].ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //erro.SetErro(38);
                                throw new Exception();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {

                            string txt = null;
                            i++; //Moacir 28062017 - soma 1 no contador para igualar a coluna do excel para visualização do usuário
                            txt += "Coluna " + dsPlan1.Tables[0].Columns.IndexOf(dsPlan.Tables[0].Columns[i].ColumnName);
                            txt += " com nome vazio no arquivo! Favor verificar!";
                            MessageBox.Show(txt, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    string txt = null;
                    txt += "Coluna " + dgvMostrar.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                    txt += " em duplicidade no arquivo! Favor verificar!";
                    MessageBox.Show(txt, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu dicidi re-escrever o seu algoritmo. A partir do momento que consegue obter o nome das colunas pode verificar se há colunas duplicadas da seguinte forma

```
var nomeDasColunas = dsPlan1.Tables[0].Rows[0].Select(r => r.ToString());
var haColunaSemNome = nomeDasColunas.Any(n => string.IsNullOrEmpty(n));
if(haColunaSemNome){
    //erro.SetErro(38);
    throw new Exception();
}
var colunaDuplicada = nomeDasColunas.GroupBy(n => n)
    .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Count() > 1)?.Key;
if(colunaDuplicada != null){
    var txt = "Coluna " + colunaDuplicada
        + " em duplicidade no arquivo! Favor verificar!";
    MessageBox.Show(txt, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
```